# Can Postgres tables be optimized by the column order?

Tags: postgresql, database-design, sybase

I recently had to propose a set of new Postgres tables to our DB team that will be used by an application I am writing. They failed the design because my table had fields that were listed like so:

```
my_table
    my_table_id : PRIMARY KEY, AUTO INCREMENT INT
    some_other_table_id, FOREIGN KEY INT
    some_text : CHARACTER VARYING(100)
    some_flag : BOOLEAN
```

They said that the table would not be optimal because `some_text` appears before `some_flag`, and since `CHARACTER VARYING` fields search slower than `BOOLEAN`s, when doing a table scan, it is faster to have a table structure whose columns are sequenced from greatest precision to least precision; so, like this:

```
my_table
    my_table_id : PRIMARY KEY, AUTO INCREMENT INT
    some_other_table_id, FOREIGN KEY INT
    some_flag : BOOLEAN
    some_text : CHARACTER VARYING(100)
```

These DBAs come from a Sybase background and have only recently switched over as our Postgres DBAs. I am thinking that this is perhaps a Sybase optimization that doesn't apply to Postgres (I would think Postgres is smart enough to somehow *not care* about column sequence).

Either way I can't find any Postgres documentation that confirms or denies. Looking for any battle-worn Postgres DBAs to weigh-in as to whether this is a valid or bogus (or conditionally-valid!) claim.

Comment: No, a column order has no impact on performance in PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 3):

Speaking from my experience with Oracle on similar issues, where there was a big change in behaviour between versions 9 and 10 (or 8 and 9) if memory serves (due to CPU overhead in finding column data within a row), I don't believe you should rely on documented behaviour for an issue like this when a practical experiment would be fairly straightforward and conclusive.

So I'd suggest that you create a test case for this. Create two tables with exactly the same data and the columns in a different order, and run repeated and varied tests. Try to implement the entire test as a single script that can be run on a development or test system and which tells you the answer. Maybe the DBA's are right, and you can say, "Hey, confirmed your thoughts on this, thanks a lot", or you might find no measurable and significant difference. In the latter case you can hand the entire test to the DBA's, and explain how you can't reproduce the problem. Let them run the tests.

Either way, someone is going to learn something, and you've got a test case you can apply to future (or past) versions.

Lastly, post here on what you found ;)

Comment: I think the difference mainly shows when doing a **lot** of updates to the table (in that case the variable-length data at the beginning needs to be shifted around). But I don't think one would actually be able to measure those differences unless you are running a ***really*** busy system.

Comment: Not familiar enough with PG internals to comment, really. But I suspect that all following data in the block might have to be rewritten if there are subsequent rows in the block, and that would make the difference rather insignificant. Must ... resist ... urge ... to ... investigate ...

Comment: @DavidAldridge: Wouldn't rewriting the whole data page block readers?

Comment: Not familiar enough with the internal mechanisms of Postgres to say, but it doesn't in Oracle so it wouldn't have to

Answer (score 1):

From a **database design** point, there is no difference between your design and what your DBA suggests -- your application should not care. In relational databases (logically) there is no such thing as order of columns; actually if order of columns matters (logically) it failed 1NF.

So, simply pass all create table scripts to your DBAs and let them implement (reorder columns) in any way they feel it is optimal on the physical level. You simply continue with the application.

Database design **can not** fail on order of columns -- it is simply not part of the design process.

---

> Future users of large data banks must be protected from having to know
>   how the data is organized in the machine ...
>
> ... the problems treated hare are those of data independence -- the
>   independence of application programs and terminal activities from
>   growth in data types and changes ...

*E.F. Codd ~ 1979*

> Changes to the physical level ... must not require a change to an
>   application ...

[**Rule 8: Physical data independence**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codd_rules) (*E.F. Codd ~ 1985*)

---

So here we are -- 33 years later ...

Comment: I'm very sympathetic to your point of view Damir, but I think that the reality is that the DBA's will make a pronouncement of what they believe to be best practice (and my experience has been that DBA's believe many, many things that vary from "true-in-some-previous-version" to "true-in-a-different-database" to "total rubbish") and force everyone to comply. They won't adopt a procedure of re-ordering columns themselves, and I don't think that it's desirable that they do since it introduces the possibility of typos, development delays, and code versioning problems.

cont ...

Comment: ... cont

In this case there may be some basis to their belief, as there used to be with Oracle (high CPU overhead when accessing right-most columns in a table) -- it would be well worthwhile to find out whether it is a valid concern in Postgres.

Comment: Why? A DBA can search for slow queries on a DB server and add indexes any time without need to consult developers. Why would this be any different? To a developer it should not matter how a DBA likes his bytes aligned on a disk.

Comment: @DamirSudarevic - you made some excellent points. I dusted off some of my CS cobwebs and read the wikipedia entry of 1NF, but couldn't understand what you meant when you said "*actually if order of columns matters (logically) it failed 1NF...*". Would you mind (for my edification) taking a few setences to explain why? Thanks again, and +1!

Comment: 1NF means that `table` has to be representation of some `relation` (relational-variable); order of rows does not matter; order of columns does not matter; no duplicate rows; each row-cloumn intersection has exactly one value of column-type (no repeating groups); no special columns (row-object ids..) .

Comment: It's no different, but it would be a rare DBA that I would trust with either situation. They don't understand the application or the way it's used, too many of them don't understand the RDBMS enough (Oracle in particular), and barely any of them know enough about software development to use source control and manage system versioning.

I may be at the point where experience sounds like cynicism, but that's why I advise that a well-structured and open test beats all opinion and experience.

Answer (score 1):

What your DBA's are probably referring to, is the access strategy for "gettting to" the boolean value in a given tuple (/row).

In THEIR proposed design, a system can "get to" that value by looking at byte 9.

In YOUR proposed design, the system must first inspect the LENGTH field of all varying-length columns [that come before your boolean column], before it can know the byte offset where the boolean value can be found.  That is ALWAYS going to be slower than "their" way.

Their consideration is one of PHYSICAL design (and it is a correct one).  Damir's answer is also correct, but it is an answer from the perspective of LOGICAL design.

If the remark by your DBA's is really intended as "criticism of a 'bad' design", then they deserve to be pointed out that LOGICAL design is **your** job (and column order doesn't matter at that level), and PHYSICAL design is **their** job.  And if they expect **you** to do the PHYSICAL design (**their** job) as well, then there is no longer any reason for the boss to keep them employed.